# Early 2000s novel where girl wakes up to find (almost) everyone gone. Turns out to be an experiment

Tags: story-identification, novel

This girl wakes up in her house in the morning, everything is the same but so very silent. She gets up and goes around, surprised to find the door unlocked and her parents gone. In fact, nobody seems to be present. Not even her neighbors. She takes the car and goes on a journey, finding a couple young adults like herself.

There are scenes in my mind in the form of broken pieces of memories...like cold meat in a food store they could not heat up or them trying to find decent clothes. Turns out they are on a planet exactly made to look like Earth but it isn’t.

I do remember the ending, an astronaut comes on the planet they inhabit and explains how this is an experiment and if they wish to go back their memories are to be erased. Everyone does except our main character and her love interest. And I remember something about them sitting on the couch and watching something in the end....

Comment: Same as [Teen wakes up to find he's alone in a major city; turns out he's part of a strange psychological experiment on another planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72767/4495)?